# 'stage' parameter for building the boost: "don't know how to make <e>stage"

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I am trying to install boost v.1.54 on windows 7(Version 6.1.7601). The cygwin with mingw, gcc and g++ compilers are installed.

I need to use the 'stage' parameter for building the boost; however it produces the following error:

```
C:\boost\tools\build\v2>b2 --prefix="C:\boost_build" toolset=gcc  --build type=complete gcc stage
notice: could not find main target stage
notice: assuming it is a name of file to create.
don't know how to make <e>stage
...found 1 target...
...can't find 1 target...

C:\boost\tools\build\v2>
```

So far I have received NO reply from the boost-build community. I appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

---

Additional comments:

- I am using the windows command prompt and gcc/g++ compiler are in the
  path and tested before.
- I ran bootstrap before the build command.
- I am running the commands from the "boost\tools\build\v2" as it's
  been stated by the guideline.
- The build procedure without the 'stage' option parameter is
  successful.

Comment: Are you using a cygwin shell or a windows prompt?

Comment: Did you remember to run `bootstrap` first? The following is from the official [Boost Windows build guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-from-the-command-prompt). Open the command prompt and change your current directory to the Boost root directory. Then, run 
`bootstrap` and then `.\b2`. The first prepares the Boost.Build system for use, the second invokes Boost.Build to build the separately-compiled Boost libraries.

Comment: Does cygwin understand "C:\"? Maybe "/cygdrive/c/" instead

Comment: I am using the windows command prompt and gcc/g++ compiler are in the path and tested before.  @doctorlove

Comment: I ran bootstrap before the build command @Stig-Magnus-Halvorsen

Comment: I am running the command from the "boost\tools\build\v2" as it's been stated by the guideline @cv_and_he

Comment: It understand because when the gcc/g++ compiler was not in the path it was complaining about the compiler @doctorlove

Comment: Thanks @cv_and_he . The problem is The Boost C++ Libraries come as source code, but there are some important binary libraries are required to be built. There are prebuilt binaries for win but they are only for Visual Studio.

Comment: As you are using gcc, instead of the Visual C++ compiler, it is recommended to build it on Windows using Boost.Build instead of the regular bootstrap -> .\b2 procedure. Follow the instructions at the [official site](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As @Stigmha pointed out very often it is the case that we can avoid building boost by using the MSVC compiled version of binary.
2. Response from Boost.Build community:

> 1. If the goal is to build all the boost tools, then you have to run the build commands from the boost build root.
> 2. --prefix is meaning-less if you're doing a 'stage' build of Boost, as it only matters when doing an 'install' build.
> 3. --build-type is spelled with a dash in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the correct solution to this problem is to run your command, with dash in --build-type, from the C:\boost folder, not the C:\boost\tools\build\v2 folder.  Hope that helps.